# Taking the average

Tags: r, average

I have a list of three data frames, each with n columns (6 in this case) and r rows (3 in this case). I want to create a matrix with the same dimensions (n*r) of the average of the three data frames within the list. So, for instance, [1,1] of the output matrix should be the average of 0.2470748, 0.2558439 and 0.2439057. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`+`, lis)/length(lis)
#         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
#[1,] 0.2489415 0.2825572 0.3033121 0.3011313 0.3560603 0.5091391
#[2,] 0.2033602 0.2516646 0.2805718 0.2855458 0.3428526 0.4959503
#[3,] 0.1841235 0.2362422 0.2771326 0.2821553 0.3382137 0.4888071
```

---

Or another option is `apply` (as mentioned in the comments by @Ananda Mahto)

```
apply(simplify2array(lis), c(1,2), mean)
#        [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
#[1,] 0.2489415 0.2825572 0.3033121 0.3011313 0.3560603 0.5091391
#[2,] 0.2033602 0.2516646 0.2805718 0.2855458 0.3428526 0.4959503
#[3,] 0.1841235 0.2362422 0.2771326 0.2821553 0.3382137 0.4888071
```

The advantage of `mean` function is that if there are NA values, we can use `na.rm=TRUE` as argument.

Comment: Is this [r] tag? From the question I can't tell

Comment: @fedorqui  I think when the question got posted, there was the `r` tag, but it could have deleted by normal wear and tear.

Comment: OK, [I see](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35669335/revisions). I just saw your profile and was curious if any of your answers was not in the [r] tag, so I checked `user:3732271 -[r]` and this appeared :D

Comment: Note this is not criticism, I just felt curious! Thanks for your efforts in this topic